# Create a downloadable file in C# (Umbraco)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, download, httpcontext

For a recent project, We're trying to create a downloadable file in C# Umbraco, but I can't seem to get it to work. For the download I'm using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response. The function is called after a button is pressed in Umbraco CMS. The function is called, but doesn't respond with a download. The function is implemented in a class that inherits from System.Web.Http.ApiController.

I'm aware that this question matches some other questions, but I've tried different solutions and I feel like I'm overlooking something.

Source code:

```
[Route("feedback")]
[HttpPost]
public void Add(FeedbackRequest feedback)
{
    var Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    string filePath = "C:\\testfile.txt";
    var file = new FileInfo(filePath);

    if (file.Exists)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

        //Doesn't work with plain/text either
        Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
        Response.Flush();
        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        try
        {
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException err)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You appear to be using ASP.NET MVC: what's wrong with returning a [`FilePathResult `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult(v=vs.118).aspx) from your action?

Comment: Im not using a MvcController, so I'm not able to use a method like filepathresult. My controller is an ApiController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my js. I had:

```
            $http.get('/someurl/Export').             
             success(function (data) { 
                //console.log(data); 
                $scope.importOutput = data; 
        });
```

The fix was:

```
window.open('/someurl/Export', '_blank');
```

Thanks for all the answers. I assumed the js was fine, because it was handling the call, but it appears it was not.

Answer (score 0):

You have your method set as void, it should be returning a result

```
public ActionResult Add(FeedbackRequest feedback)
{   
    string filepath = "some filepath";
    byte[] filedata = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
    string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);

    var contentInfo = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = "download filename",
        Inline = false,//ask browser for download prompt
    };

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentInfo.ToString());

    return File(filedata, contentType);
}
```

Comment: When trying that I'm getting the following in the return:
Non-Invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: I have tried letting my controller inherit from the MvcController to allow the use of File as a method, however now it's not able to find my paths. I'll look further into it.